# LG TONE earbuds - what‘s the difference?

Tags: audio, headphones, earphones

(Hey, so i was searching for a (relatively) cheap pair of in ear wireless headphones with decent audio quality, ac doesn’t matter to me. Now i stumbled upon a seemingly good deal on a pair of lg tone headphones but) looking up the difference to other versions, i couldn’t even find **official** specs for all of them. It‘s confusing - it’s nothing complicated, nonetheless some aren’t even listed anywhere besides (trusted) retailer sites. So: **what *is* the difference between all the lg tone (free).. fp 9 8 7 6 5 fn 6 7 5u etc etc ?**

Stuff like:

Quality

Design changes

Release date

Qi charging case

That interesting/funny uv case feature

(And if you want, you could maybe note own experiences if some models should be ignored anyways.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, i somehow found it now:

fn4 are pretty much just [true wireless headphones](https://www.google.com/search?q=what+is+true+wireless) without any extras (although some, like me, actually don't like active noise cancelling anyways because many implementations create pressure and hurt your ear even more over time) but still cost more than some others at this point in time.

fn5u has active nc and the uv anti bacteria cleaning

fn6 is the same but qi charging box instead of active noise cancelling

fn7 has all of the above

As it seems there's none which's audio features you can't control via the extra app.

The dfp lineup seems to have more microphones and LG claims them to have better audio. Their shape also seems slightly different to me, although which design is better may be subjective. Furthermore the feature to use one bud as microphone for whispering on phone calls seems exclusive to the dfp line-up and ear caps from some medical material. They still have the uv cleaning btw.

Besides that:

dfp3 (not even meridian sound if that really makes any difference)

dfp5 (ac)

dfp8 (ac and qi loading case)

dfp9 (no qi but „plug and wireless“)

I hope this is a simple helpful list for anyone who wants to buy a pair.

Although the better ones aren‘t really budget products anymore of course.